# MongoDB $and operator with nested objects in arrays not working as expected

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, mongodb-query

I have nested array database records styled as such:

```
{
"_id" : "A",
"foo" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "a",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-07-13T23:27:13.522Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "b",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-08-04T22:36:36.381Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "c",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-08-23T23:59:40.202Z")
    }
]
},
{
"_id" : "B",
"foo" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "d",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-07-17T23:27:13.522Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "e",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-01-06T22:36:36.381Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "f",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-09-14T23:59:40.202Z")
    }
]
},
{
"_id" : "C",
"foo" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "g",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-11-17T23:27:13.522Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "h",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-06T22:36:36.381Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "i",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-10-14T23:59:40.202Z")
    }
]
}
```

When I run the query:

```
db.bar.find(
    {
        $and: [
                  {"foo.date": {$lte: new Date(2017,8,1)}}, 
                  {"foo.date": {$gte: new Date(2017,7,1)}}
       ]
    },
    {
       "_id":1
    }
)
```

I'm returned

```
{ 
    _id: "A"
},
{ 
    _id: "B"
},
{ 
    _id: "C"
}
```

Logically I'm asking for only the records where at least one date is between Aug-1 and Sept-1 (Record A), but am getting all records.

I'm thinking it might be referencing different dates on the subdocuments i.e. where foo.1.date > Aug-1 and foo.0.date < Sept-1.

Has anyone else had issue and found a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filters are evaluated separately against each subdocument in your array and that's why you're getting all results. For instance for C

- element with _id g is gte 1st of August
- element with _id h is lte 1st of September

You should use $[elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to find date in specified range

```
    db.bar.find(
    { "foo": 
        { 
            "$elemMatch": 
                { "date": 
                    { 
                        "$gte": new Date(2017,7,1), 
                        "$lte": new Date(2017,8,1) 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
    })
```

Only A will be returned for this query.

Comment: Thanks, I was suspecting that was the issue. $elemMatch was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing doensn't work as you want for array.

You have to unpack the array and after you compare the values.

```
 db.bar.aggregate(
// Unpack the assignments array
{ $unwind : "$foo" },

// Find the assignments ending after given date
{ $match : {
    "foo.date": { $gte: new Date(2017,7,1),$lt: new Date(2017,8,1)  }
}}
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a valid response, but for my use case required using "find".

Answer (score 0):

This should also work fine

```
 db.bar.find({"foo.date": { $gte: new Date(2017,7,1),$lt: new Date(2017,8,1)  }})
```

Comment: yes, that's equivalent to the query I was running in my initial post. Make a collection with the sample data I provided and you'll see that it returns [A, B, C]